# A function for cleaning string from unsecure inputs, destroys input and return empty string PHP

Tags: php, security, joomla, code-injection

When i give form value to this function, always, an empty string returns.

```
<?php
function safeinput($data)
{
    $data = trim($data);
    $data = stripslashes($data);
    $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
    $data = mysql_real_escape_string($data);
    return $data;
}
?>
```

Is there another way to secure inputs?
note : Operations done under joomla

Comment: Did you connect to a database before you called `mysql_real_escape_string`?

Comment: you need to pass a connection to the function and pass is to mysql_real_escape_string. The resource is out of scope, even if you have one open.

Comment: It would be better to use a database class

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/129677/whats-the-best-method-for-sanitizing-user-input-with-php

Comment: Why are you `mysql_real_escape_string` when you have a perfectly good API to help you? You do also realise this `mysql_*` is deprercated

Comment: @Lodder is totally right, why in the world would you be doing any filtering like this inside Joomla? THe point of using a framework is to use the framework. Even if you are not using JForm use JFilterInput().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way is the ensure you are limiting you input based on expected value types. You can refer this

docs.joomla.org/J1.5:Retrieving_and_Filtering_GET_and_POST_requests_with_JRequest::getVar

or

http://api.joomla.org/cms-2.5/classes/JRequest.html

possible filters are

- INT
- INTEGER
- FLOAT
- DOUBLE
- BOOL
- BOOLEAN
- WORD
- ALNUM
- CMD
- BASE64
- STRING
- ARRAY
- PATH
- USERNAME

the you can escape the data using.

```
    $db= JFactory::getDbo();
    $db->getEscaped($data);
```

http://api.joomla.org/cms-2.5/classes/JDatabase.html#method_getEscaped